# Positioning divs in a circle with sine and cosine

Tags: css, math, sass, geometry, trigonometry

So I am wanting to position my divs in a circle, and this is what I have so far.

[Here's](http://codepen.io/samirc/pen/KzMMKB?editors=0100) the codepen if you want to check it out live.

SCSS

```
$num: 200;

$angle: 0;
$step: (pi())/10;


@for $i from 1 through $num {

  $angle: $step + $angle;
  //$radians: rad($angle);

  $mar: $num;

  $top: $i  * cos($angle);
  $left: $i * sin($angle);

  .cir:nth-child(#{$i}) {

    margin-left:$left + px;
    margin-top:$top + px;

    background: hsl($i*pi(), 50, 70);
    opacity:0.8;

    border-radius: 50%;
    //border:1px solid gray;

    width:5px;
    height:5px;

    position:absolute;

    opacity:0;


    animation:no-#{$i} 1s ease infinite;
    animation-delay:$i*0.01s;


  }
```

Haml (Just a loop that spits out 200 divs)

```
- 200.times do
    .cir
```

Using this algorithm I was able to create something like this:
[image: Circle trail from the center]

I know for a fact it's increasing from the center, and that the space between the current div and the next one increases every time.

I was trying to make it so that each circle is maybe at 360/(numberOfDivs) degree until the divs have formed a circle, and the below image is kind of an example with much fewer circles:

[image: circle out of circles from google]

I hope I'm making sense, if so, I would greatly appreciate any help.

I know there is something wrong with my algorithm: (probably in this area)

```
$top: $i  * cos($angle);
$left: $i * sin($angle);
```

and hope someone knows how to fix it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:
Big circle with radius `R` centered at `CX, CY`
Problem:
Place `N` small circles around the big one without gaps

At first we have to find a radius of small circle `r`:
Centers of big and small circles and touch point form right rectangle with hypotenuse `R+r`, angle `Pi/N` and leg(cathetus) `r`. So simple trigonometry gives us the formula:

```
r = (R + r) * Sin (Pi/N)
r  = R * Sin (Pi/N) / (1 - Sin(Pi/N))
```

(quick check for 6 circles gives angle `Pi/6` and `r = R` - true)

Now we can calculate center coordinates for i-th small circle:

```
XC[i] = CX + (R + r) * Cos(i * 2 * PI / N) //round to integers if needed
YC[i] = CY + (R + r) * Sin(i * 2 * PI / N) //angles in radians
```

If you need topleft coordinates of bounding square, just subtract `r` from the values calculated above

```
$num: 12;

$step: 2*pi() / $num;

@for $i from 1 through $num {

  $angle: $step * $i;

  $top: use my formula
```

Comment: Could you please write this in compliance with my code, I'm not sure how to implement in with what I already have, but I'll keep trying nonetheless, thank you by the way!